# Schema design in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana

My use case for influxDB is for storing and trending process data coming from different PLCs. I visualize this data using grafana. In a first pilot, I used the schema design guidelines from influxDB, using a generic measurement name and separating the different value sources by means of tags.

For example, when I have 2 pumps in the 'acid' pump group and 2 pumps in the 'caustic' pump group of which I recond the pressure:

```
- pump_pressure {pump: pump_1, group: acid} 
- pump_pressure {pump: pump_2, group: acid} 
- pump_pressure {pump: pump_1, group: caustic} 
- pump_pressure {pump: pump_2, group: caustic}
```

In my use case,  the end-user wants to be able to make their own trends using Grafana for example. While this way of recording the data is conform the schema design guidelines of influxDB (I think), it is very confusing for non technical people that are not used to working with and thinking in SQL like languages.

Therefore, I'm tempted to store the data in the way that they are used to, and is the general way of working in similar products (historians):

```
- ACID_pump_1_pressure
- ACID_pump_2_pressure
- CAUSTIC_pump_1_pressure
- CAUSTIC_pump_2_pressure
```

This would make it much easier for the end user to make trends, as 1 measurement = one data source, and they don't have to worry about `where` and `group by` clauses.

Can anyone point me to some clues what the impact of the latter would be on influxDB performance and storage. Will the data take more space in this way? Please not that the latter method can lead to a few thousand measurement, but their cardinality would all be 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no reason you can't do that if it fits your use-case better. The guidelines that you start with are there because it unlocks the full power of InfluxDB's tagging capability.

There will be no performance or storage implications. Internally, InfluxDB creates a new series based on each unique measurement "key", where the key is the combination of measurement name and tag key/value pairs.

ie, each of these is a separate series:

```
pump_pressure,pump=pump_1,group=acid
pump_pressure,pump=pump_2,group=acid
pump_pressure,pump=pump_1,group=caustic
pump_pressure,pump=pump_2,group=caustic
```

also, each of these is a separate series:

```
ACID_pump_1_pressure
ACID_pump_2_pressure
CAUSTIC_pump_1_pressure
CAUSTIC_pump_2_pressure
```

EDIT, source: I work at InfluxData

EDIT 2, this being said, I also agree fully with @srikanta and I would recommend keeping the tags, but finding another solution to interacting with the users of the db (or educating).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you can go with this approach. However this is not scalable. What if the number of pumps used increases ? Then too, this approach works where the number of pumps is equal to the number of time series. However it becomes a pain to manage.

If the problem to avoid the interaction of the non technical user with the SQL queries then different approach to that should be considered and not to alter the "schema" of the database.

Some more insights --> https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/influxdb-design-guidelines-to-avoid-performance-issues/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The measurements typically required in factories are not as easily structured as server CPU loads and memory usage across datacenters for example. When a user is interested in a pump flow, he wants the flow of that pump and not of any other. I would like to know I there is a performance / storagepenalty if I would use separate measurements for each value?

Comment: @coussej AFAIK, there are no penalties in terms of storage or performance if you store a particular type of value per time series basis like "A" time series consists of flow value of all the pumps and "B" time series consists of another parameter of all the pumps. Since queries when done are specific to a time series, you wouldn't see any difference compared to storing multiple types of values in a single time series. And remember, a database can have multiple time series (just as a Table in a SQL DB)